# jquery loop links

Tags: jquery

i have a php-loop that generates different results from the database, so my output might look like this:

```
<a href="blablabla">blabla</a> <a href="blablabla">blabla</a> <a href="blablabla">blabla</a> <a href="blablabla">blabla</a> <a href="blablabla">blabla</a> <a href="blablabla">blabla</a>
```

Now, I know how to get a clicked element by #id or .class but I don't know (and havent found) how to get a clicked link. (I wont to show the content of it's link in an other div. Do you have a solution?

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? can you give a example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $("targetDivSelector").load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: Do you need the content from that link into the div

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understood your question, but is this what you were after?

```
$(function() {
    $('.yourlink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#someDiv').load(this.href);
    });
});
```

Or maybe it was this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.yourlink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#someDiv').html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this~

```
 $(function(){
    $('a').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').live('click',function(e){

     e.preventDefault();
     var link = $(this).attr('href');

     $('.somediv').html(link);

});
```